# Order by aggregate in same table in Django queryset

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

I am trying to order a Django queryset according to an aggregate on the same table.

The model is as follows:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    cpn = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

What I want is for the resulting queryset to be ordered according to the minimum price of a cpn. I can do this in SQL with an inner join, but cannot figure out how to do it in Django.

Example:

```
# select * from thing;

 id | cpn |  name   |  price
----+-----+---------+----------
  3 | 1   | poihg   |       12
  5 | 2   | slkgh   |       11
  6 | 2   | zxcb    |       13
  7 | 3   | wertyui |        1
  8 | 3   | wegwbn  | <<NULL>>
  2 | 1   | lkhgf   | <<NULL>>
  4 | 2   | welkgh  |        9
  1 | 1   | ered    |        8
```

The expected ordering is:

```
# select * from thing
  inner join
    (select cpn, min(price) as min_price from thing group by cpn) as t1
  on thing.cpn = t1.cpn
  order by
    min_price desc, t1.cpn, price is not null desc, price desc;

 id | cpn |  name   |  price   | cpn | min_price
----+-----+---------+----------+-----+-----------
  6 | 2   | zxcb    |       13 | 2   |         9
  5 | 2   | slkgh   |       11 | 2   |         9
  4 | 2   | welkgh  |        9 | 2   |         9
  3 | 1   | poihg   |       12 | 1   |         8
  1 | 1   | ered    |        8 | 1   |         8
  2 | 1   | lkhgf   | <<NULL>> | 1   |         8
  7 | 3   | wertyui |        1 | 3   |         1
  8 | 3   | wegwbn  | <<NULL>> | 3   |         1
```

I could use Thing.objects.raw, but I'm looking for a solution using regular querysets, as the view that needs this ordering gets a queryset from somewhere else, and the resulting queryset will be used in a form.

The backend database is PostgreSQL, and I am not against not portable solutions.

**ANSWER**

schillingt's comment put me on the right track. By using a foreign key, I can get the ordering I want.

Comment: If you make cpn a ForeignKey you could do it with the following ```annotate(min_price=Min('cpn__thing_set__price')).order_by('min_price')```. If you don't want to do that, then I suggest you look into ```extra``` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#extra

Comment: I looked into ````extra```` but couldn't figure how to do the join. I'm not against making cpn a ForeignKey, I'll see if I can work it out. Thanks.